# Why do method declarations evaluate to nil in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

Defining a method doesn't seem to evaluate to a truthy value as can be checked by putting one inside an `if` condition:

```
if(def some_method; puts "random text"; end) then
  puts "declaration evaluates to true"
else
  puts "declaration evaluates to false"
end
# => declaration evaluates to false
```

Why/How does a method declaration evaluate to `nil`?

Comment: Why would you *WANT* to do that? It's completely random and, in a code-review, would be flagged immediately as anti-idiomatic and unsupportable.

Comment: Your question is undefined because method declaration does not evaluate to `false`. It evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: @theTinMan I guess you are missing the point. The OP did not do this for a practical purpose. Probably this was the only way the OP could think of to verify that the return value of a method definition in not truthy.

Comment: @sawa: My fault. I should have been more careful to research before posting the question. I have corrected it in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I understand the truthy-ness question quite well. IRB would have been one of many ways I'd have tested it. Putting a method definition in an `if` condition isn't one of them.

Comment: @theTinMan: May I ask you why are you so allergic to that `def` inside `if` condition?

Comment: When coding in production environments, it's important to follow code-styles to avoid unexpected/unknown behavior. Defining a method in the conditional runs afoul of Ruby's programming idiom, plus that of every other language I've ever written in (which is a pretty long list). I understand you were trying to figure out the truthy-ness of `def`. Just don't do it in "real" code you are writing in a team situation; It doesn't buy you anything and it would cause consternation and confusion among those working with you, which wouldn't be good.

Comment: To explain it a bit better -- when writing code, at home for yourself, when experimenting with an idea at work, or when maintaining someone else's code, it's a really good idea to write as if your job depended on it. Write clearly, cleanly and concisely. Use meaningful variable, method and class names, and comment when necessary. I agree with, and follow, 99% of what's in https://github.com/styleguide/ruby. I vary from it a little based on my programming experience, but, with those minor changes, my team at work follows it closely. Make it a habit to write code that way.

Comment: @theTinMan: +1 for ruby style guide mention. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually evaluates to `nil`. This makes sense; why would a method creation return anything?

```
irb(main):001:0> def test; print 'test'; end
=> nil
```

However, it has to return something, so to return "nothing" would be to return `nil`.

Comment: IMO it should return a black-hole which immediately sucks the user's keyboard into the monitor, forever denying them use of a keyboard again.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Why *wouldn't* creating a method return anything? After all, creating an object returns something, right? In Rubinius, for example, `def` actually *does* return the `CompiledMethod` object for that method. And a lot of people have argued that `def` should return either the `UnboundMethod` object for that method or a `Symbol` corresponding to its name.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: This has got me thinking about how different various implementations of ruby are... +1 for your Rubinius mention!

Answer (score 2):

Every statement in Ruby evaluates to something.  The `def` statement's value is not supposed to be checked and is therefore `nil`.

You will find the behavior you are looking for in the reflective "meta-programming" method `define_method`.

```
class EmptyClass

  m = define_method(:newmethod) {p "I am the new method"}
  p m # => <Proc:0x50b3f359@E:\NetBeansProjects\RubyApplication1\lib\main.rb:6>

end
```

Comment: +1 `The def statement's value is not supposed to be checked ` says it all.

Comment: On Rubinius, `def` returns the `CompiledMethod` object for that method.

Answer (score 1):

From [Ruby gotchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#.22Gotchas.22):

> Boolean evaluation of non-boolean data is strict: 0, "" and [] are all evaluated to true. In C, the expression 0 ? 1 : 0 evaluates to 0 (i.e. false). In Ruby, however, it yields 1, as all numbers evaluate to true; only nil and false evaluate to false. A corollary to this rule is that Ruby methods by convention — for example, regular-expression searches — return numbers, strings, lists, or other non-false values on success, but nil on failure. This convention is also used in Smalltalk, where only the special objects true and false can be used in a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

Method definions such as `def some_method; puts "random text"; end` always return **nil**.

Now, that means the method is evaluated to **nil**. According to the Ruby Documentation:

> Returns false if obj is nil or false; true otherwise.

Since your method return **nil**, **if** will evaluate it as **false** therefore execute the else statement.